# TFF: How simulate training on random samples of users in each round

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I would like to simulate this code of federated learning for image classification with random samples of users in each round,
This tutorial uses all clients on training, insteed, I would to modify this code in such a way, in each round a random samples of clients are chosen.
 So what we can change in this code to force it to choice client randomly

```
import collections
import time

import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()

import tensorflow_federated as tff

source, _ = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data()


def map_fn(example):
  return collections.OrderedDict(
      x=tf.reshape(example['pixels'], [-1, 784]), y=example['label'])


def client_data(n):
  ds = source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(source.client_ids[n])
  return ds.repeat(10).shuffle(500).batch(20).map(map_fn)


train_data = [client_data(n) for n in range(10)]
element_spec = train_data[0].element_spec

def model_fn():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(784,)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, kernel_initializer='zeros'),
      tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
  ])
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      model,
      input_spec=element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])


trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn, client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.02))

....
NUM_ROUNDS = 11
for round_num in range(2, NUM_ROUNDS):
  state, metrics = trainer.next(state, federated_train_data)
  print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics))
```

Answer (score 2):

`tff.simulation.ClientData` objects expose a [`client_ids`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/ClientData#attributes) attribute, which represents a list of the strings identifying the users in this dataset.

So you can sample from this list directly, and use the `create_tf_dataset_for_client` method on the same object to create a dataset of this user's data. Assuming a `tff.simulation.ClientData` object `client_data`, the pseudocode would look like:

```
import random
...

for round_num in range(2, NUM_ROUNDS):
  selected_clients = random.sample(client_data.client_ids, USERS_PER_ROUND)
  federated_data = [
      client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(n) for n in selected_clients]
  state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_data)
```

Much of the research code included in TFF somewhat separates the concern of selecting clients from running the training loop, so I can't really point to a good example of this pattern there--but TFF I think would be happy to accept a contribution updating the tutorials to use a pattern like this, to help show the flexibility of the `ClientData` API a little better.

Comment: Yeah! But it can be however many you want--there are thousands of users in this dataset if I recall correctly

Comment: Thanksmy gentelmen, but  this triggered  an error    `TypeError: The target type `  `<x=float32[?,784],y=int32[?]>* is not assignable from source type   ``<label=int32,pixels=float32[28,28]>* `

Comment: Ah, it looks to me like this client data needs to be preprocessed. Try preprocessing this client data with a function like `lambda example: collections.OrderedDict(x=tf.reshape(example['pixel'], [-1, 784]), y=example['label'])`. If this code snippet is coming from the tutorial, there should be a preprocessing function there.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This will do it (following Keith's pseudocode):

```
selected_clients = np.random.choice(emnist_train.client_ids, size=USERS_PER_ROUND)
round_federated_train_data = make_federated_data(emnist_train, selected_clients)
```